# How to use Altium Multi-Board to define SODIMM board and socket connections?

Tags: connector, altium, memory

I am attempting to use Altium 18.1.9's new "Multi-Board" feature to connect a 200-pin SODIMM board ---> to a SODIMM socket connector ---> on my mainboard PCB. [This Altium article](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/((Capturing+the+Logical+System+Design))_AD) is just about the only documentation I can find on how to go about doing this, and I don't think it explains what I need.

1. For the SODIMM board, I have created the schematic library symbol with all 200 unique pin names and functions. I have not created a PCB library footprint for this board, because I did not design the board, and I'm not sure I even need a footprint.
2. For the 200-pin SODIMM socket connector, I have created the schematic library symbol and PCB library footprint layout, which will connect (1) to (3). I added the "System: Connector" part parameter as shown in the Altium doc link above.
3. I have created my mainboard schematic (which includes the SODIMM connector), created the PCB, and placed the SODIMM connector footprint on it. Because of adding the "System: Connector" parameter in (2), I can see the connector in Altium's Multi-Board schematic project:

[image: .MbsDoc]
I am not sure what to do next. Should I create a new PcbProj just for the SODIMM board, add it to the PrjMbd, and define the SODIMM board as a "System: Connector"? Do I add another SODIMM socket to that project also?

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Multi-board is a newish feature, with limited collective user experience.  You would be better served by asking this on the official Altium forum, where active users would be more likely to be experimenting with this.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that later, and post the answer here if someone can help.